# Can't serve static assets from docker containers behind Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, create-react-app

I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to serve two containers. Here is a part of my Nginx conf file:

```
upstream dashboard {
    server dashboard:80;
}

upstream editor {
    server editor:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://dashboard;
    }

    location /editor/ {
        rewrite ^/editor(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass         http://editor;
    }
```

I'm getting 404 errors when I navigate to the `/editor` url in my browser because the page is submitting requests for static resources that reside in the upstream container, "editor".

[image]

I'm pretty new to Nginx but I presume when it receives a request with the url:
`http://example.com/static/css/2.3d394414.chunk.css`

Nginx has no way of knowing that the corresponding css is located inside the `editor` container. How can I amend the configuration to fix this problem? I've seen some configurations which provide a common path to any static assets but I need a solution that can handle assets within docker containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you have static resources on `editor` and `dashboard` upstreams and in both cases the URL is the same `/static/some.resource`
Because you cannot differentiate based on the URL you could configure `nginx` to try if the file exists on `dashboard` first and proxy the request to `editor` if not found.

```
 upstream editor {
    server editor:80;
   }

   upstream dashboard {
     server dashboard:80;
   }

   server {
     location /static {
     # Send 404s to editor
     error_page 404 = @editor;
     proxy_intercept_errors on;

     proxy_pass http://dashboard

     }

     location @editor {
       # If dashboard does not have the file try with editor
       proxy_pass http://editor
     }
   }
```

See also [nginx – try files on multiple named location or server](http://linuxplayer.org/2013/06/nginx-try-files-on-multiple-named-location-or-server)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've already changed the directory structure of the static assets in the `editor` and `dashboard` apps to avoid the problem of nginx not being able to differentiate them. Your solution seems to work without the need for that though, I just don't want to change the code back to try it ;)

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error -  "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters the same problem, here's an additional answer as well as the one posted by @b0gusb. This is a solution when you have docker containers as the upstream applications. `dashboard` and `editor`, for example, are containers comprising of [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) applications and an nginx server.

Firstly, change the directory where the `index.html` file, generated by `create-react-app`, searches of the static assets by setting the `homepage` field in the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "homepage": "https://example.com/dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Using the current latest version of `react-scripts` (3.1.1) this will generate an index.html file with links to your static assets which are expected to reside inside the `dashboard` directory (or whatever name you choose after the slash in the `homepage` field).

Now in your docker file you need to do some moving of build assets so that the links in the `index.html` do not break. The following is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install react-scripts@3.1.1 -g
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.2

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build/*.html /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Notice that the static assets generated by `create-react-app` build, are located inside the `dashboard` directory and the `index.html` in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory.  Now your nginx reverse proxy can differentiate requests for different static assets of your various containers:

```
    # location to handle calls by the editor app for assets
    location /editor/ {
        proxy_pass http://editor/editor/;
    }

    # location to handle calls by the dashboard app for assets
    location /dashboard/ {
        proxy_pass http://dashboard/dashboard/;
    }

    # location to handle navigation to the editor app
    location /editor-path/ {
        access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;
        rewrite ^/editor-path(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass         http://editor/;
    }        

    # location to handle calls to the rest/graphql api
    location /api/ {
        access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;
        rewrite ^/api(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass         http://restserver/;
    }

    # location to handle navigation to the dashboard app
    location / {
        access_log /var/logs/nginx/access.log;
        proxy_pass         http://dashboard/;
    }
```

Comment: I like this solution better. It avoids making unneeded requests.

Answer (score 0):

put the **/editor** configuration above the **/** configuration.

Nginx perform checks from top to bottom, so it's possible that having the root configuration ( **/** ) on top will route all contents to the wrong server.

Switch the blocks location and restart/reload nginx configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Could you add a specific location block for static content before the /editor block?

Comment: I've tried adding `location /static/ { proxy_pass: http://editor; }` before the /editor block. That causes static requests for the dashboard app to return 404, however. I guess the reverse proxy can't then distinguish between static requests for the `dashboard` and `editor` apps.

Comment: no, if you have same location for both, it will be redirected. would it be possible for you to assign a 3rd level dns to filter application? like app1.localhost.me and app2.localhost.me ? DNS could filter calls and let you avoid this behavior

Comment: I like that idea, much more elegant. I don't have control over the company domain names, however. I've almost got it working by changing the file structure of the static asset locations in the `dashboard` and `editor` apps though. That way nginx can differentiate the static requests. I don't like that solution tbh, it means that each app needs some custom configuration for the benefit of nginx but it's all I can think of to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for easy configuration, you can follow this:

```
upstream dashboard {
    server dashboard:80;
}

upstream editor {
    server editor:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://dashboard;
    }

    location /editor/ {
        proxy_pass         http://editor;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        sub_filter "/static" "/editor/static;
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
```

`sub_filter` function will change example.com/static/ become example.com/editor/static, but for best configuration you must make one path for all static files. Like:

> /var/data/build/dashboard/.. (can be css, js)
>
> /var/data/build/editor/.. (can be css, js)

I think use `sub_filter` is good while the app doesn't have many URLs to rewrite with, I hope this helps.