# Nginx reverse-proxy not serving static files

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, docker-compose

I tried to start some services via docker-compose. One of them is a **nginx reverse-proxy**, handling different paths. One path ("/react") is to a **containerized react_app with a nginx** on port 80. Solely, the reverse-proxy is working correctly. Also, if I server the nginx of the react_app on port 80, all work's fine. Combining both **without changing** anything in the config leads to 404 for static files like css and js.

**Setup #1**
Correct forward for path /test to Google.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"

services:
  #react_app:
  #  container_name: react_app
  #  image: react_image
  #  build: .
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

*nginx.conf* (reverse-proxy)

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://www.google.com/;
}
```

**Setup #2**
No reverse proxy. Correct answer from nginx inside of container react_app.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"

services:
  react_app:
    container_name: react_app
    image: react_image
    build: .
  #reverse-proxy:
  #  image: nginx:latest
  #  container_name: reverse-proxy
  #  volumes:
  #   - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  #  ports:
  #    - '80:80'
```

**Setup #3 (not working!)**
Reverse proxy and React App with nginx. Loads index.html, but fails so load files in /static

*nginx.conf* (reverse-proxy)

```
location /react {
    proxy_pass http://react_app/;
}
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"

services:
  react_app:
    container_name: react_app
    image: react_image
    build: .
  reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: reverse-proxy
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Activating both systems leads to failing static content. It seems to me that the reverse-proxy tries to server the files, but fails (for good reason), because there is no log entry in reac_app's nginx. Here's the config from the reac_app nginx, perhaps I'm missing something out.

*nginx.conf* (inside react_app container)

```
events {}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

**--> Update**

This is a rather unsatisfying workaround - but it works. Although now reacts routing is messed up. **I cannot reach /react/login**

```
http {
    server {
        server_name services;

        location /react {
            proxy_pass http://react_app/;
        }

        location /static/css {
            proxy_pass http://react_app/static/css;
            add_header  Content-Type    text/css;

        }
        location /static/js {
            proxy_pass http://react_app/statics/js;
            add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not giving any information to the reverse proxy on how it should handle your request with respect to the React app. All you're saying is listen for calls on port 80 and resolve any call to index.html, which probably doesn't exist. I expect your React app to be running on port 3000, right?

Comment: The reverse-proxy is using the internal domain name via proxy_pass http://react_app/. Therefore the nginx of react_app serves at 80. I've tried to run it on port 3000 and use the nginx on my machine (not inside docker), which show the same behaviour.

A index.html does exist properly on path `/usr/share/nginx/html` in react_app container

Comment: Sorry, missed that part, didn't realise that setup #3 uses things from previous ones. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642492/cant-serve-static-assets-from-docker-containers-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy, maybe it will clear things up.

Comment: Hi guys, I have this exact same issue. @DeVolt did you manage to work it out?

Answer (score 6):

If you check the paths of the missing static files in your browser, you'll notice their relative paths are not what you expect. You can fix this by adding sub filters inside your nginx reverse proxy configuration.

```
http {
    server {
        server_name services;

        location /react {
            proxy_pass http://react_app/;

            ######## Add the following ##########
            sub_filter 'action="/'  'action="/react/';
            sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/react/';
            sub_filter 'src="/'  'src="/react/';
            sub_filter_once off;
            #####################################
        }
    }
}
```

This will update the relative paths to your static files.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but the react routing problem remains. Nginx responses to routes e.g. /login, which should be forwared to index.html

Comment: I fight with this for 3 days :) . THANKS!